# C++ user input restriction with proper retry without "goto"

Tags: c++, validation, iostream, goto, istream

I have the following code:

```
qstn:
  cout << "Input customer's lastname: ";
  getline(cin, lname);

  if (lname.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ") != string::npos) {
      cout << "You can only input alpha here!\n";
      cin.clear();
      goto qstn;
  } else if (lname.empty()) {
      cout << "Please enter your firstname!\n";
      cin.clear();
      goto qstn;
  }

  int lnamel = lname.length();
  int strl = str.length();
  int is = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < strl;) {
      i++;
      is++;

      if (lname[i] == lname[is] && lname[i] == ' ' || lname[0] == ' ') {
          cin.clear();
          cout << "Please input your lastname properly!\n";
          goto qstn;
      }
  }
  // next question here
```

I'm having a hard time on thinking what will be the proper logic to avoid the
goto statement, since I was college I was using it but someone here said that
it's not good to use it at all cause it might ruin my code.

I tried using the do while loop but it's not smooth as goto.

Please help!

Comment: Are you simply asking why you shouldn't use `goto`, or asking people to re-write your code without `goto`? Please look at [How to Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, as an aside, the hatred of goto derives from Dijkstra trying to force structured programming into a world that didn't want it. Not using goto isn't "good practice"; it's _a 40-year-old irrelevancy taken out of context_. The _predecessor_ to the language you're using hadn't even been invented yet, and Bjarne Stroustrup was still _a minor_.

Comment: @imallett: Spoken (or typed) like somebody who never dealt with code in (for example) FORTRAN II. Some didn't immediately realize that they wanted structured programming, but it wasn't just Dijkstra advocating it, nor was there really any significant resistance to it. The biggest sore point at the time was simply lack of languages that provided better ways to do things.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Indeed. But either way, speaking purely for myself, I am _amazed_ that essentially no one is aware of how little the no-goto rule as Dijsktra originally posed it applies to today's languages. So now students (such as this one) are growing up thinking that `goto` shouldn't ever be used, without ever learning that that's a misinterpretation of an obsolete paper written before we went to the moon by a guy long-since dead. Obnoxious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function:

```
bool getLastName(string & lname,
                 string & str)
{
    cout << "Input customer's lastname: ";
    getline(cin, lname);

    if (lname.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ")
            != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "You can only input alpha here!\n";
        cin.clear();
        return false;
    }
    else if (lname.empty())
    {
        cout << "Please enter your firstname!\n";
        cin.clear();
        return false;
    }
    int lnamel = lname.length();
    int strl = str.length();
    int is = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < strl;)
    {
        i++;
        is++;
        if (lname[i] == lname[is] && lname[i] == ' ' || lname[0] == ' ')
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Please input your lastname properly!\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

All I've done here is replace the `goto`s with `return false`. If the program makes it to the end of the function, `return true`. Make the function call in a while loop:

```
while (!getLastName(lname, str))
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Not only does this de-spaghettify the code, but it breaks it up into nice, small, easy to manage pieces. This is called [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming).

Comment: Or, as with my approach, you get **[this ~9 line `main`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/334b4f6a976d34cc)**. This is called [declarative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idiom I like to use:

```
int i;

if (std::cin >> prompt("enter an integer: ", i))
{
    std::cout << "Read user input: " << i << "\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Input failed (too many attempts). Eof? " << std::boolalpha << std::cin.eof() << "\n";
}
```

Here, `prompt` is a smart input manipulator, that takes care of handling parse errors or stream failures and retrying.

It's quite generic so actually do many things, but you don't need to indicate all the options. When the manipulator is inserted into the stream it relays to the `do_manip` member:

```
template <typename Char, typename CharT>
friend std::basic_istream<Char, CharT>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<Char, CharT>& is, checked_input<T, Prompter>& manip) {
    return manip.do_manip(is);
}
```

The `do_manip` handles all the logic **without any `goto`s** :) :

```
std::istream& do_manip(std::istream& is) {
    auto attempt = [this] { return infinite() || retries_ > 0; };

    while (attempt()) {
        if (!infinite())
            retries_ -= 1;

        prompter_(out_);

        if (is >> value_) {
            if (!run_validators(out_))
                is.setstate(is.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit);
            else
                break;
        } else {
            out_.get() << format_error_ << "\n";
        }

        if (attempt()) {
            is.clear();
            if (flush_on_error_)
                is.ignore(1024, '\n');
        }
    }

    return is;
}
```

You can see that there is a possibility to have validations run before accepting the input.

Here's a somewhat full-blown demo:

**<kbd>[Live On  Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbc009379948372b)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    using namespace inputmagic;

    int i;

    if (std::cin >> prompt("enter an integer: ", i)
            .retries(3)
            .flush_on_error(false)
            .format_error("I couldn't read that (Numbers look like 123)")
            .output(std::cerr)
            .validate([](int v) { return v > 3 && v < 88; }, "value not in range (3,88)")
            .validate([](int v) { return 0 == v % 2; })
            .validate([](int v) { return v != 42; }, "The Answer Is Forbidden")
            .multiple_diagnostics())
    {
        std::cout << "Read user input: " << i << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Input failed (too many attempts). Eof? " << std::boolalpha << std::cin.eof() << "\n";
    }
}
```

You can see it will only accept valid integers

- that are >3 and <88,
- that are even
- except 42 (forbidden number)

When entering the numbers 21, 42 and 10 on subsequent retries, you get: **[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbc009379948372b)**

```
enter an integer: 21
Value not valid
enter an integer: 42
The Answer Is Forbidden
enter an integer: 10
Read user input: 10
```

However, if you enter 1 all the time you get this: **[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d614abf89e11c3a4)**

```
enter an integer: 1
value not in range (3,88)
Value not valid
enter an integer: 1
value not in range (3,88)
Value not valid
enter an integer: 1
value not in range (3,88)
Value not valid
Input failed (too many attempts). Eof? false
```

Or if you read from a single line file: **[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3edf4a4688b64679)**

```
enter an integer: value not in range (3,88)
Value not valid
enter an integer: I couldn't read that (Numbers look like 123)
enter an integer: I couldn't read that (Numbers look like 123)
Input failed (too many attempts). Eof? true
```

Answer (score 0):

A While loop looks like your best bet. You can redo the loop with the continue keyword.

```
int incorrect = 0;
while(!incorrect) {
cout<<"Input customer's lastname: ";
        getline(cin,lname);

        if(lname.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ")!=string::npos)
            {
            cout<<"You can only input alpha here!\n";
            cin.clear();
            continue;
            }
        else if(lname.empty())
        {
            cout<<"Please enter your firstname!\n";
            cin.clear();
            continue;
        }
        int lnamel=lname.length();
        int strl=str.length();
        int is=0;
        for(int i=1; i<strl;)
        {
           i++;
           is++;
           if(lname[i]==lname[is]&&lname[i]==' '||lname[0]==' ')
           {
               cin.clear();
               cout<<"Please input your lastname properly!\n";
               continue;
           }
           incorrect = 1;
        }
```

Comment: `while(!incorrect)` implies that you should be looping while something is correct. The variable should be named correct, so you are looping while input is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some do while loops
for instance this:

```
qstn:
            cout<<"Input customer's lastname: ";
            getline(cin,lname);

            if(lname.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ")!=string::npos)
                {
                cout<<"You can only input alpha here!\n";
                cin.clear();
                goto qstn;
                }
            else if(lname.empty())
            {
                cout<<"Please enter your firstname!\n";
                cin.clear();
                goto qstn;
            }
```

could be re-written as this:

```
int flag;
do{
    flag = 1;
    cout<<"Input customer's lastname: ";
    getline(cin,lname);
    if(lname.find_first_not_of( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ")!=string::npos)
    {
        flag = 0;
        cout<<"You can only input alpha here!\n";
    }
    else if(lname.empty())
    {
        flag = 0;
        cout<<"Please enter your firstname!\n";
    }
    cin.clear();
} while( flag !=1 );
```

feel free to use a boolean type flag, it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code suffers from lack of clarity of purpose.

You apparently don't want the string that's entered to include a leading space, nor multiple consecutive spaces. Other than that, only alphabetic characters should be accepted.

If the user does enter multiple consecutive spaces, I'd probably just ignore all but the first. I'd probably write the code something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

bool non_alpha(std::string const &s) {
    return !std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c) || std::isspace(c); });
}

std::string get_name(std::string const &prompt) {
    std::string result;
    std::string line;

    do {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
    } while (non_alpha(line));

    std::istringstream words(line);
    std::string word;
    while (words >> word)
        result += word + ' ';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto res = get_name("Please enter last name, alpha-only\n");
    if (res.empty())
        std::cout << "Oh well, maybe some other time";
    else
        std::cout << "Thanks Mr(s). " << res << "\n";
}
```

I'd be tempted to consider doing roughly the same for non-alphabetic characters--rather than asking the user to re-enter from the beginning, assume it's a mistake and just ignore it.