# cin.fail check repeats cout error message for multiple cin'd characters

Tags: c++, cin

I'm having a slight problem with my cin.fail check. I tried doing some research to find something that relates to my answer, but I can't really find anything that's the same issue as mine. Here's a sample script:

```
cout << "Type in the base stat amount: ";
cin >> baseStat;

while (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Error! Base stat must be a number! Try again: ";
    cin >> baseStat;
    baseStat = floor(baseStat);
}
```

For reference sake "baseStat" is a float, and I floor my float because I need it to be a whole number for a formula in this particular case.

What I'm trying to do here is I'm trying to say if the input is anything that's not a float or whole number, then it's an error. As it currently stands my code works as intended, however it only seems to work when you type in one character, such as "a" or "#". If for instance I were to input "asdf" instead, I get something like this:

*"Error! Base stat must be a number! Try again: Error! Base stat must be a number! Try again: Error! Base stat must be a number! Try again: Error! Base stat must be a number! Try again: "*

I'm not quite sure how to fix this, I thought maybe using a for loop to reset baseStat to 0 before the while loop could do the trick, but it still repeats four times.

Comment: Elephant in the room: If you need a input as a whole number, why read in a float? Why not read in an integer type and not have the problem in the first place?

Comment: My mentality was that if I went for a float instead of an int then I could avoid a validation check for decimals, but I suppose that isn't the way I should be thinking if that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Hey, you got two answers, but no upvotes neither comments. Are you really interested in getting an answer ? All this site is about feedback...

Answer (score 0):

If you want input validation, I suggest you input a string and convert it to an `int`, by checking if it's possible. Something like this:

```
int baseStat = 0;
std::string input;
do
{
   std::cout << "Type in the base stat amount: ";
   std::cin >> input;
   try {
       baseStat = std::stoi( input );
   }
   catch( ... )
   {
      std::cout << "Invalid value, try again\n";
   }    
}
while( basestat == 0 );
```

This assumes you have access to C++11 (which should be the case).

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

Like it or not, you're doomed to have a test. In this case something like

```
if (baseStat - floor(baseStat) == 0.0)
```

looks like it would work.

But first a warning: due to inaccuracy inherent in floating point numbers if you need an integer or fixed point value, use an integer. With floating point value you may get what looks like a nice round 1.0 right up until you do math on it, and then you find that it was actually 0.999999999997 and rounded off to look pretty when you printed it out.

If you are handling North American money, don't do it in dollars with a `double`. Do it in cents with an `int`. Save you a lot of trouble.

For your current problem, Try this:

Make `baseStat` a suitably large integer ( I went with `long long` here) then, read the whole input line from the user

```
for ( ; ; ) // keep looking until the user inputs a good value
            // feel free to put a limit on how stupid a user is allowed to be. 
{
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(cin, line)) // read in a while line of user input
    {
        try
        {
            // try to convert the user's input to a long long int
            std::size_t cnv;
            baseStat = std::stoll(line, &cnv);  

           // if we converted everything the user put in
            if (cnv == line.length())
            {
                break; // got a good one. Stop looking
            }
        }
        catch(std::logic_error &)
        { 
            // didn't convert to a valid integer at all
        }
    }
}
```

And if you really want to get deep, and have a nice, generalized, permanent solution check out sehe's answer here: [C++ user input restriction with proper retry without "goto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358682/c-user-input-restriction-with-proper-retry-without-goto)