# A way to not accept float as input c++

Tags: c++, input, floating-point, int

I'm working on a project where I need to check for the correct input (n), I currently have a bit of code which won't allow string to be entered as it will ask again for a correct amount. I'm having trouble writing a code that won't allow float numbers to get through as it currently just ignores the float part of the input. I'm sorry if this is a simple question, but I haven't found a way to get around this yet.

```
  for(int i=0; i<1; ++i)
    {
        string b1;
        int e;
        do
        {
            getline(cin,b1);
            e=atoi(b1.c_str());
        }
        while(e==0 && b1!="0");
        n=e; // where n is the user input
    }
```

Comment: So where is your problem ? Are you trying to input a float & put it to an `integer e` using `atoi` ? Or you are doing something else ?

Comment: You could use `strtol`. It takes an extra parameter that tells you where it stopped parsing. If it encounters a non-digit character, that extra parameter will end up pointing at that character; otherwise, it'll point at the terminating NUL.

Comment: as I wrote in the original question this part only deals with strings as it will reject any string input. what I'm trying to find out is a way to do the same with float. I only want int inputs and I want to reject float inputs.

Comment: Tajke a look at sehe's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358682/c-user-input-restriction-with-proper-retry-without-goto

Comment: [Also look at `std::stoi.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) It is a bit more cumbersome than [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), but will catch cases where the value was too big to fit with a little less gymnastics.

Comment: @user4581301 - A lot more gymnastics. You need a "try ... catch" with `std::stoi`, but with `std::strtol`, and checking whether there's junk at the end is just as easy with either one.

Comment: @DavidHammen The out-of-range case for `strtol` and family requires testing output against max and min, then checking `errno` for `ERANGE` to make sure the max or min really is an overflow and not legitimately max or min. In `stoi` you have a slow-but-easy-to-write trip through an exception block. The rest of the checking is equally easy in `stoi` and `strtol`.

Comment: @user4581301: No need to check against max and min at all, just set `errno` to zero beforehand and check after.  (Zeroing `errno` beforehand is needed, otherwise you could fail to convert a valid minimal or maximal value)

Comment: Now I am wondering how many valid min-maxes I've chucked through the years because of a stale value in errno. Regardless, thanks, @BenVoigt. I'm going to correct and simplify some code on Monday morning.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you consider anything with decimal point (`'.'`) or using scientific notation with a negative exponent as a non-acceptable floating point number, just check if the entered string contains one of those:

```
std::string::iterator it;
if (b1.end() != std::find(b1.begin(), b1.end(), '.')
    || (b1.end() != (it = std::find_if(b1.begin(), b1.end(),
                                       [](char c){ return c == 'e' || c == 'E'; })
        && it + 1 != b1.end()
        && '-' == it[1])) {
    // deal with the string being a floating point number with a fractional part
}
```

Note, that this will consider, e.g., `"10e-1"` to be a bad value although it is actually just a fancy spelling of `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a `float` value then it will have a `decimal point (.)`. As your input is a `string` hence you can do the following check :-

```
do
{
     getline(cin,b1);
     if(bi.find(".")!=b1.npos); // search if a decimal point is present or not
     cout<<"wrong input";
     else
     e = stoi(b1);  // stoi works similar to atoi but on strings
}
```

Comment: Just use the second parameter of `stoi` to detect parsing failure, which gets rid of the need for a separate step calling `find`.

Comment: What if the user enters 1e-1? There's no decimal point, but that is not an integer.

Comment: @DavidHammen truly speaking even `std::stoi` fails to give correct output when you use such expression. So i m helpless

Comment: The second parameter distinguishes integers from integers with trailing garbage (which includes `1e-1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stringstream` for this purpose :-

```
for(int i=0; i<1; ++i)
    {
        string b1;
        char c=' ';
        int e=0, check=0;
        do
        {
            getline (cin, b1);
            stringstream ss(b1);
            ss >> check;
            if(ss>>c)
            cout << "bad input";
            else
            e=check;
        }
        while(e==0 && b1!="0");
        n=e;
    }
```

Comment: Fails to trap the float, the exact case OP asked about.

Comment: it detects float doesn't it ?

Comment: If you input 3.14, it will output 3 rather than rejecting it as not an `int`. All you've done is output a message saying the input is wrong, you still let it through.

Comment: @user4581301 i guess now you would have no issues

Comment: Only one. `e` is now being used unininitialized in while after bad input. A quick `e=0;` above the do will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you want to do is not repeat the code over and over ever time you want to read an integer. Make a function:

```
int getInt(std::istream & in)
```

This will take any input stream, `cin`, a file, a `std::stringstream`, whatever. Next we set up a few local variables we need.

```
{
    std::string b1;
    int e;
```

Now we build the input loop

```
    while (std::getline(in, b1))
```

This will loop until the input stream fails. If it never fails and the user can't get their act togehter, we'll be here for a long long time. With Gilligan. The Skipper too. Maybe we can bum some money off of Mr. Howell for start-up seed capital, eh?

```
    {
        size_t pos;
```

Catch any exceptions thrown by the string -to-int conversion

```
        try
        {
```

Convert to `int`. `pos` will be updated with the character that ended the conversion. If it is not the end of the string, the string does not contain an `int`. If it does contain an `int`, we exit the function and return the `int`.

```
            e = std::stoi(b1, &pos);
            if (pos == b1.length())
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
```

We don't really need to do anything in the catch block. You could output a message to instruct or mock the user if you wish.

```
        catch (...)
        {

        }
    }
```

If we got here, the IO stream failed and we need to let folks know. Throw an exception.

```
    // IO failure. throw exception
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
int value = getInt(cin);
```

You may wish to wrap the call in an try-catch block to catch the IO failure exception. `cin`'s failure cases are pretty weird and usually fatal, though.

When calling `getInt` on a file you will want to handle things more carefully because end of file is a common occurrence.

All together without the running commentary:

```
int getInt(std::istream & in)
{
    std::string b1;
    int e;
    while (std::getline(in, b1))
    {
        size_t pos;
        try
        {
            e = std::stoi(b1, &pos);
            if (pos == b1.length())
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {

        }
    }
    // IO failure. throw exception
}
```

Comment: One issue: `pos == b1.npos` isn't the right test.  You should use `pos > 0 && b1[pos] == 0`

Comment: Shoot. I knew I should have run it. Thanks @BenVoigt

Comment: Hmm, that's better in case you have embedded NULLs (shouldn't be possible when reading from a stream), but you still are mishandling empty input.  You need the `pos > 0` test I mentioned.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The `pos>0` test is not needed.`std::stoi` will throw an exception if no conversion is possible (e.g., empty string, or `"junk"`). Getting past the call to `std::stoi` means the value in `pos` has to be positive.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Thanks for reminding me why I always use the well-behaved version (`strtol`)

Comment: @BenVoigt - Using `strtol` does avoid the need for a try-catch, but at the expense of a more complicated `if` statement.

Comment: To be honest, I screwed this up because I use `strtol` most of the time. I'm trying to use more C++11 (and more C++ in general). `strtol` seems to be a bit faster in the failure cases, probably the exception handling, but around here I'm trying a slightly different hierarchy of needs: correct first, then safe, simple, and speed only if OP specifically asked for it.

Comment: @BenVoigt `std::stoi` isn't that cumbersome as you feel,you just need to use it a few more times. It's safe, easy & justified. I rather feel that `strtol` has a more complicated syntax than this. It doesn't matter because `std::stoi` internally uses `strtol` only with more safety

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: Sorry, I don't agree with "just need to use it a few more times".  Using exceptions to handle expected parsing failures is an anti-pattern.